# call second Retrofit request after getting response of first request

Tags: android, request, retrofit, retrofit2

First Request : **ReceiveNewDataFromServer()**

Second Request: **SendNewDataToServer()**

Currently both request sending parallely with successful response but getting **sometimes conflict with data.**

Is there any solution to Request one after another?

P.S. I am thinking to put second request in "success" callback of first, but may that will take more time.

Comment: put second request in "success" callback of first, that will be the only way to make the requests linear

Comment: Yes you can use RXjava here for this purpose

Comment: Or you can use interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi you can use RX java in android for these kind of purposes basic example i'll show you. You can use **ZIP** operator.

```
fetchFromGoogle = fetchFromGoogle.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());

fetchFromYahoo = fetchFromYahoo.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());
```

To handle the first scenario in which both requests need to run in parallel, you can use the zip operator and subscribe to the Observable it returns.

```
// Fetch from both simultaneously
  Observable<String> zipped  = Observable.zip(fetchFromGoogle, fetchFromYahoo, new Func2<String, String,  String>() {
  @Override 
  public String call(String google, String yahoo) {
      
// Do something with the results of both threads

            return google + "\n" + yahoo;

  }
     });
```

Here is the [example](https://github.com/saveendhiman/SampleApp/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/sampleapp) how we can call apis' through RX java from retrofit.This is the Architecture of android app with latest technologies.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer for who don't have a knowledge of RxJava. If you are not comfortable with RxJava then you can use the nested call from retrofit but if you have more code to manage then I would suggest using the RxJava.

```
apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

        Call<MovieResopnse> call = apiInterface.getTopRatedMovie(API_KEY);
        final Call<List<Language>> callLanguage = apiInterface.getLanguages(API_KEY);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<MovieResopnse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<MovieResopnse> call, Response<MovieResopnse> response) {
                movies = response.body().getResults();
                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: Number of movies received: " + movies.size());

                Picasso.get()
                        .load(IMAGE_URL + movies.get(item).getPosterPath())
                        .into(image);

                title.setText(movies.get(item).getOriginalTitle());
                subtitle.setText(movies.get(item).getTitle());
                description.setText(movies.get(item).getOverview());
                rating.setText("" + movies.get(item).getVoteAverage());
                release_date.setText("Release: " + movies.get(item).getReleaseDate());

                // Request another api after getting language code from the first one.
                callLanguage.enqueue(new Callback<List<Language>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<List<Language>> call, Response<List<Language>> response) {
//                languageList = new ArrayList<>();
                        Log.d(TAG, " Request url : " + call.request().url().toString());
                        languageList = response.body();

                        for (Language language1 : languageList) {
                            if (language1.getIso6391().contains(movies.get(item).getOriginalLanguage()))
                                language.setText(language1.getEnglishName());
                        }
                        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + languageList.size() + " Languages");
//                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: "+languageList.get(0).getEnglishName());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<List<Language>> call, Throwable t) {
                        // Log error here since request failed
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.getMessage());
                        Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: request url : " + call.request().url().toString());
                    }
                });


            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<MovieResopnse> call, Throwable t) {
                // Log error here since request failed
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.getMessage());
                Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: request url : " + call.request().url().toString());

            }
        });
```